# user defined functions

Tags: c#, .net, sql, user-defined-functions

I have this user defined function.

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    static int i;
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
    public static SqlSingle f()
    {
        return new SqlSingle(1.3F);
    }
};
```

But it only works if `i` is readonly. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also 'works' if is read-write.

If by 'not works' you mean the assembly cannot be installed in SQL because it contains a static field, use of static class variables is dangerous for reasons explained in [CLR Hosted Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131047.aspx):

> Given these considerations, we
>   discourage the use of static variables
>   and static data members of classes
>   used in SQL Server. For `SAFE` and
>   `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` assemblies, SQL Server
>   examines the metadata of the assembly
>   at `CREATE ASSEMBLY` time and fails the
>   creation of such assemblies if it
>   finds the use of static data members
>   and variables.

Mark your assembly as UNSAFE as a sign that you understand the risks associated with static variables and SQL will accept your assembly.